# how to update with angular firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving users successfully with afb:

```
//retrieve users        
afb.collection('Users').valueChanges()
.subscribe(results => { 
this.users = results;
 })
```

But then I need to update a LoginCount properry for a user by id:

```
var user = this.users.find(x => x.UserId === userId);   
user.LoginCount = user.LoginCount + 1;
afb.doc('/Users/' + user.$key).update(user);
```

Does this appear to be a correct way to do an update in Angular Firebase?  The first problem I'm having is that the found user doesn't have a $key property. What do I need to do to ensure that my db/query code includes a $key property on returned records?

Answer (score 0):

when you write console.log(x.UserId) do you get id in console that match to id in authentication for that user? If yes than what are parametars for user? what you want to update?

If you want to increment some object when person log's in, to count it, you should create new node in database to count for each user. This is one way:

```
this.afb.object(`/counters/${this.x.UserId}/logcounter`).query.ref.transaction((logcounter =>{
            if(logcounter === null){
              return logcounter = 1;
            } else {
              return logcounter + 1;
            }

        }));
```

If you don't get user id with writing console.log(x.UserId), you can get it :

```
this.fire.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.UserId = user.uid;

      }
    });
```

Than change: ${this.x.UserId} to ${this.UserId}.
Hope this helps you, cheers!